# Autovalidate of TextFormField after user interaction

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, dart-pub

I am developing a flutter e_commerce app, and in registration, the username should be unique, for that, we have an endpoint in API to check either the username is taken or not, my problem is with validation, I need to validate after user interaction, in flutter we have auto validate mode, but there is only(always, onUserInteraction) options, and I need the validation right after user interaction

The textFormField of the username input is

```
TextFormField(
                cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixIcon: SuffixIcon(),
                  labelText:
                      'Choose suitable name and relevant to your products',
                  hintText: 'SweetCandies',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if(value!.isNotEmpty){}
                  Provider.of<Store>(context).usernameExistence(value, 'no');
                  if(Provider.of<Store>(context).nameExistence){
                    return 'The Chosen name is already taken';
                  }
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Required';
                  }
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  Provider.of<Store>(context, listen: false)
                      .storeInformation['name'] = value!;
                },
              )
```

is there any way to active validator after user interaction???

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by 'after user interaction'?

Comment: I mean after the user end intering the value to the textFormField.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a `focusNode` to `TextField` so whenever focus changes you can make an api call and validate the text

add this code and `initState` to your code

```
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
FocusNode focusNode;
bool _hasInputError;
String errorText = "";
String text;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode = new FocusNode();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!focusNode.hasFocus) {
        setState(() {
         if(Provider.of<Store>(context).nameExistence){// your condition
            _hasInputErro = true;
            errorText = 'The Chosen name is already taken';
         }// <-- else if condition ...
         else{
           _hasInputErro = false;
         }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

in TextFormField :

```
TextFormField(
    focusNode: focusNode,// <-- add focusNode here
    controller: controller,// <-- add controller here
    cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorText: _hasInputError ? errorText : null, // <-- add this line to show errors
      suffixIcon: SuffixIcon(),
      labelText:
          'Choose suitable name and relevant to your products',
      hintText: 'SweetCandies',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
      ),
    ),
   // validator: ... , // <-- comment validator
    onSaved: (value) {
      Provider.of<Store>(context, listen: false)
          .storeInformation['name'] = value!;
    },
)
```